# Prims Algorithm MST

Tags: algorithms, spanning-trees

I have this problem :

[image]
And here's my attempted solution, [image]

could someone inform on whether it's correct

thanks

Haven't got enough reputation to make them into images so far..

Comment: Your question already includes a summary of an answer to the original problem but no question *about* this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MST looks correct.

Prim's algorithm builds the MST as follows:
Start with an empty set of nodes and edges:  $V=\{\},  E=\{\} $.

1. Add node $1$ to the MST (but any other starting node will do).
   $V=\{1\},  E=\{\} $ 
   Now consider all the nodes not in the MST that are connected to it and pick one with the lowest edge weight: 
    d(1,2) = 3, ***d(1,5) = 1***, d(1,4) = 2  
   We pick edge $(1,5)$ and add it to our edge set $E$. We add $5$ to $V$.
2. $V = \{1,5\}, E = \{(1,5)\}$
   Proceed the same way. Consider all the nodes not in the MST that are connected to it by an edge and pick an edge with the lowest weight:
   d(1,2)=3, **d(5,4)=1**, d(5,3)=2  d(5,6)=4 
   We pick edge $(5,4)$.
3. $V = \{1,5,4\}, E = \{(1,5), (5,4)\}$
   d(1,2) = 3, **d(5,3) = 2**,  d(5,6) = 4
4. $V = \{1,5,4,3\}, E = \{(1,5), (5,4), (5,3)\}$ 
   d(1,2) = 3, **d(5,6) = 1**
5. $V = \{1,5,4,3,6\}, E = \{(1,5), (5,4), (5,3), (5,6)\} $
   **d(1,2) = 3**
6. $V = \{1,5,4,3,6,2\}, 
   E = \{(1,5), (5,4), (5,3), (5,6), (1,2)\}$

We stop when $V$ has all the nodes of our graph.

Comment: My initial answer was all symbolic with no explanation, because OP just asked for confirmation.  I understand now that an answer should also benefit others stumbling upon this post. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for commenting again -- you reminded me that I'd forgotten to come back and check your answer